# Kill processes only if a specific number of PIDs match criteria

Tags: awk, kill, xargs, ps

I am trying to improve this one liner I use as an (abused) docker-compose healthcheck that runs inside a container:

`ps -C program.bin -o pid,pcpu --no-headers | awk '$2 > 98 {print $1}' |  xargs kill -9`

In current form, I filter the PIDs with CPU utilization over 98% and kill any matching PID right away.

However, I would like to kill only if an exact number of resulting PIDs have the high utilization (in other words, if one program.bin PID has CPU over 98%, don't kill it, but if 2 of them meet the criteria, kill them both).
Any pointers on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Find the cause of the high usage before becoming a serial killer!

Comment: Looks like you've reached the point where a one liner is no longer enough. Write a script, or fix the actual underlying issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
... | awk '
$2 >= 98 {c++; m[$1]} 
END { if (c >=2 ) for(i in m) print i }' | xargs -r kill -9
```

Store the process whose burn a lot of resources in an array and print them if and only more than `n` process are above the threshold, otherwise print nothing.

The `-r` option instruct `xargs` to quit without executing the command if no argument are given. Otherway execute the `kill`.

Comment: I had a hunch that storing the results in an array might be the key, but wasn't sure how to properly do it! Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed!